# Removing second password input from django-registration form

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using django-registration v1.0 for signups. By default, the signup page has 4 input fields:

- username
- email
- password1
- password2

The [django-registration documentation](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#registration.forms.RegistrationForm) justifies that the repeated entry of the password serves to catch typos. But I want to remove the second password field.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can inherit from the default form, and set the `password2` field to be excluded.

Comment: But won't it affect the form validation?

Comment: not if you inherit. If you declare your own form and inherit it from `forms.Form`, then yes

Comment: How do I do this? In forms.py? If you don't mind can you give me a simple code example? Thank you very much..

Comment: Yes, in forms.py - why dont you give it a try and edit the question if you are stuck at some point.  it is very simple, you will be amazed at how simple it is to achieve it.

Comment: I will try it and update here.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I got it working, in case it helps someone:

In `forms.py`

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('password2')
```

In `views.py`

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    form_class= UserRegistrationForm
```

In `urls.py`

```
from links.views import MyRegistrationView

url(r'^register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

Thanks to karthikr for the comments.